# ffs does not name a type in C++

Tags: c++, types

I get compilation error when i try to compile the following..... Please comment.

Here is my code: 
ffs.h

```
#ifndef FFS_H
#define FFS_H
     #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include "commands.h"

        class ffs{
        private:
            Filesystem *filesys;
            Superblock block;
            void processCommands(InputParser command);
            void performQuit();
            void performInit(InputParser command);

        public:
            void acceptCommands();
            ffs(){};
        };

        #endif
```

ffs.cpp

```
#include "ffs.h"

void ffs::acceptCommands(){
    std::string input;
    while(true){
        std::cout<< "Enter command : ";
        getline(std::cin,input);
        InputParser parser(input);
        processCommands(parser);
    }
}

void ffs::performInit(InputParser command){
    command.getCommand().pop_front();
    int n = atoi(command.getCommand().front().c_str());
    std::cout<< n << " : number of blocks "<<std::endl;
    command.getCommand().pop_front();
    int m = atoi(command.getCommand().front().c_str());
    std::cout<<m << " : number of inode blocks" << std::endl;
    command.getCommand().pop_front();
    block.ninode=m;
    Filesystem fs(n);       
    filesys = &fs;
}

void ffs::performQuit(){
    ///filesys->clean();
    exit(0);
}

void ffs::processCommands(InputParser command){
    std::string cmd=command.getCommandName();
    if(cmd.compare(commands::Q())==0) performQuit();
    else if (cmd.compare(commands::INIT())==0) performInit(command);
}
```

tester.h

```
#ifndef TESTER_H
#define TESTER_H

#include "ffs.h"

class ffs;
class tester{
private: 
    ffs ffsobj;
public:
    void run(){ffsobj.acceptCommands()};
};

#endif
```

tester.cpp

```
#include "tester.h"

int main()
{
    tester runner;
    runner.run();
    return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

```
  g++  -c -Wall tester.cpp
tester.h:7: error: ffs does not name a type
tester.h: In member function void tester::run():
tester.h:9: error: ffsobj was not declared in this scope
tester.h:9: error: expected `;' before ˜} token
make: *** [tester.o] Error 1
```

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
CC=g++

all: flags.o InputParser.o commands.o Filesystem.o ffs.o tester.o
        $(CC) flags.o InputParser.o commands.o Filesystem.o ffs.o tester.o -o runner.o

flags.o : flags.cpp flags.h 
        $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) flags.cpp

InputParser.o :  InputParser.cpp InputParser.h
        $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) InputParser.cpp 

ffs.o: ffs.cpp ffs.h 
        $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) ffs.cpp

commands.o: commands.cpp commands.h
        $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) commands.cpp

Filesystem.o: Filesystem.cpp Filesystem.h Superblock.h
        $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) Filesystem.cpp

tester.o: tester.cpp tester.h ffs.o
        $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) tester.cpp

#fileUtility.o : IFileUtility.h 
#       gcc -c IFileUtility.h 
# Inode.h  commands.h Filesystem.h

clean :
        rm *.o
```

Comment: This is interesting. I don't see anything that would cause that error in the code you posted.

Comment: it complies in windows in vs but when i try to build it using a makefile

Comment: Then, the problem obviously lies within your makefile. Sadly, I know nearly nothing about them. :|

Comment: Try putting some error flags please... At least -Wall...

Comment: @Macmade no change in the error messages

Comment: Take everything from the beginning. If you include ffs.h in main, without including tester.h, are you able to create an instance?

Comment: There's a lot of bad style here, but nothing illegal.  I suspect the compiler is picking up a different copy of `ffs.h` than the one you posted here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `ffs` as your class name, it already has a meaning in c++ (albiet an obscure one). Just pick a different name.

Comment: Wow. Googling `c++ ffs` brought this question on 8th place... so it's a stdlib function. Quite unlucky to include that head and name your class like it.

Comment: @Shishya: This is the kind of thing namespaces are for.

Answer (score 1):

You got a `#endif` in your `ffs.h` file, without the befinning `#if`.

If you include `ffs.h` in your `tester.h` file, why do you declare `class ffs;` ?

Comment: its there just forgot to post it here

Answer (score 0):

do not solve the "does not name a type" problem, but look at this line:

```
void run(){ffsobj.acceptCommands()};
```

the correct is:

```
void run(){ffsobj.acceptCommands();}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense. If it's in "tester.h", it will be in "tester.cpp" if "tester.h" is included there.

Comment: since he's using a ffs object within tester.h he can't use forward declaration

Comment: so remove the forward declaration, theres no need if you already included the header

Comment: Shouldn't be the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in following line:

```
class ffs;
class tester{
private: 
    ffs ffsobj; // <--- can't declare object for ffs; can be pointer/reference only
```

To declare an object of `ffs` type, `class tester` should be able to see its full definition. Otherwise you can just declare a pointer or reference of `ffs` type, if you have forward declared like that (`ffs*` or `ffs&`).

Comment: Wrong, he included the header where `ffs` is fully defined, so everything is fine.

Comment: while compiling the `ffs.h` may not be visible as he may not have included that path for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the forward class declaration `class ffs;` from tester.h.  It is unnecessary since you include ffs.h and then confuses the compiler when it tries to define a class member which it thinks it has not seen the definition for.